For API only user to verify the login operation I need SOAP API login example
For API only user to verify the login operation I need SOAP API raw-level login example.
For example, for demo in Postman without using any external Java, C# or Apex libraries

Example:
POST
https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0

for sandboxes or
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/26.0

for production or DE orgs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><env:Header /><env:Body>
<login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>{username}</username><password>{password}</password></login>
</env:Body></env:Envelope>

Here {password} may be replaced with either the password or password concatenated with a security token.
Important headers:
 "SFDC_STACK_DEPTH" "1"
 "SOAPAction" "DoesNotMatter"
 "Accept","text/xml"
 "Content-type" "text/xml"
 "charset", "UTF-8" 

